# Fill AutocompleteTextView on letter click

Tags: android, sqlite, keypress, autocompletetextview

I am making a dictionary application, the database contains more than 50k words.I am using a `AutoCompleteTextView` for showing the words while the user searches. I think it will be a huge task to load all the data and bind with `AutoCompleteTextView` at first, so I thought of loading data when keypress event happens.

Hitting the database for every button press event is also a bad idea as it is heavy, So is there any optimal way to do this ?. Since the app size matters I am not preferring to use Realm or any other database.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-autocompletetextview-example-sqlite-database.html

Comment: http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/

Comment: just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a `FilterQueryProvider`, thats all

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830, all you need is to implement `runQuery()` method to return the `Cursor` from your sqlite database

Comment: and what? did it work?

Comment: @Andrew Medico put on hold ??? why ??

Comment: FYI, your question has been discussed [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299026/849891).

Comment: I doubt this will be reopened, as it's clearly too broad (even given the rather permissive enforcing of SO guidelines in the Android tag). It is much better for you to show readers what you have, and then answers can be made to improve upon it. Please don't include direct requests for code in _any_ of your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a filter like `FilterQueryProvider` with `LIKE %` command which will try to match character more efficiently rather than just pulling out the whole information.

Example,

```
 // select query
        String sql = "";
        sql += "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
        sql += " WHERE " + fieldObjectName + " LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'";
        sql += " ORDER BY " + fieldObjectId + " DESC";
        sql += " LIMIT 0,5";
```

Source:

[Android AutocompleteTextView with Database](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-autocompletetextview-example-sqlite-database.html)

**Performance optimization tips:**

Create index for your column and avoid scan operations by running a query analysis. Scan operations are much slower than search operations.

Source:  [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)

Comment: no need for any CustomAutoCompleteTextView, just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a `FilterQueryProvider`, thats all

Comment: so now tip #2 is no longer valid (by the way Handler is not a background task)

Comment: Is `searchTerm` user input, and if so is it escaped in any fashion prior to being merged into a query?

Answer (score 3):

Activity:

```
AutoCompleteTextView text;
String[] languages= {"Android ","java","IOS","SQL","JDBC","Web services"};

text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
ArrayAdapteradapter  = newArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,languages);

text.setAdapter(adapter); 
text.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: Define Autocomplete in your xml first.

Comment: before that please read the question

Answer (score 3):

You can with the help of addTextChangedListener() do this in very few steps.

You can refer to [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/11/android-autocompletetextview-example-sqlite-database.html) also.